# Get the last modified file's epoch time in current directory

Tags: rhel, find, aix, printf

I need to get the epoch time which belongs last modified file in current directory. I have some limitations:

- must be compatible with RHEL and AIX systems
- AIX does not allow `-printf` option with `find` command
- Can't use `stat` command

It is a bit challenging.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Try the stat() function from perl.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, the OP has already done their research in that they identified GNU `find -printf` or `stat` solutions and the fact they couldn't be used on AIX.

Comment: Related: [Full file date (without GNU utilities)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/255524)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you are wrong. i tried to find a proper way,  unfortunately could not find a solution. All the solutions i found work on rhel but AIX. Just wanted to explain myself.